# Is there anyway to convert a float to a brightness value for a pixel?

Tags: colors

You can cycle through a bitmap image and get the brightness of each pixel as a float value between 0 and 1.

But is there anyway of doing the reverse?

As in you take a brightness value, and you convert that to a brightness of a pixel. Obviously you wouldn't have any colour but that doesn't matter.

All I want to do is take a float and get a pixel with a brightness corresponding to that float value. So 0.0 would become black, 1.0 would become white and 0.5 would be in-between.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out.

I just had to multiply the float value against 255 and then use the rounded integer in the RGB fields:

```
int n = (int)(255 * brightness)
Color c = Color.FromArgb(n, n, n)
```